# Attach database to SQL Server Express automatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have created a winforms application with Visual Studio 2010 and a setup project for it. My application works with SQL Server Express so I have added SQL Server 2008 Express to the list of prerequisites of the setup.

In addition I have used the following connection string to connect to my database :

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|MyDBName.mdf; Integrated security=True;
```

My application and its setup project build successfully but when I have installed and run it (even as administrator) I receive an error :

> cannot open a user default database.login failed. login failed for
>   this user.

What is my mistake??

Comment: try adding `;User Instance=True` in the connection string

Comment: I have tried it already but it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528768/cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-after-installing-sql-server-m

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/24cbe0d8-c439-4cf3-9999-5dd8f02ed2c9/

Comment: Hi HaLaBi,Thanks. your first suggestion work for me.I have used User Instance again and it was worked.I do not know why at the first time it did not work.